# Align Images from Database on horizontal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put all the images from database side by side, but they are always appearing like a vertical list. How can i put in a Horizontal list?

```
.column5 img
{ display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}

<?php
$ligax=mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
if($ligax) {
    mysqli_select_db($ligax,'database');
    if(!mysqli_error($ligax)) {
        $query="select * from marcas";
        $result = mysqli_query($ligax,$query);
$nregistos = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for ($i=0; $i <$nregistos; $i++)  {
      $registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $cod_marcas=$registo['cod_marcas'];
            $hiperligacao=$registo['hiperligacao'];
            ?>

        <div class="column5">   <center>
            <?php 
            echo ("<a href=$hiperligacao><img src=\"showfile.php?cod_marcas=$cod_marcas\">");?>
            </div>
             <?php  
        }
    }
}

</a>
</section><!--/#bottom-->
```

Comment: this is not a php or database problem but a css issue, remove the php and database tags, then only post the raw html produced by the php and the css then do a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
.column5 a { 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.column5 a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}

<?php
$ligax=mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
if($ligax) {
    mysqli_select_db($ligax,'database');
    if(!mysqli_error($ligax)) {
        $query="select * from marcas";
        $result = mysqli_query($ligax,$query);
$nregistos = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for ($i=0; $i <$nregistos; $i++)  {
      $registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $cod_marcas=$registo['cod_marcas'];
            $hiperligacao=$registo['hiperligacao'];
            ?>

        <div class="column5">    
            <?php 
            echo "<a href=$hiperligacao><img src=\"showfile.php?cod_marcas=$cod_marcas\"></a>";?>
            </div>
             <?php  
        }
    }
}

</a>
</section>
```